# Bus error opening and mmap'ing a file

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems

I want to create a file and map it into memory.  I think that my code will work but when I run it I'm getting a "bus error".  I searched google but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int file_fd,page_size;
    char buffer[10]="perfect";
    char *map;

    file_fd=open("/tmp/test.txt",O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC ,(mode_t)0600);

    if(file_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 2;
    }

    page_size = getpagesize();

    map = mmap(0,page_size,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,file_fd,page_size);

    if(map == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 3;
    }

    strcpy(map, buffer);

    munmap(map, page_size);
    close(file_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger (so compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and debug with `gdb`)

Comment: You have a variable `page_size`, but you seem to be using `pege_size` in your call to `mmap()`

Comment: The `addr` in `mmap()` should be `NULL` and not `0`.

Comment: Thank you.I tried null for addr but result didn t change.

Answer (score 23):

You are creating a new zero sized file, you can't extend the file size with mmap. You'll get a bus error when you try to write outside the content of the file.

Use e.g. [fallocate](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html)() on the file descriptor to allocate room in the file.

Note that you're also passing the page_size as the offset to mmap, which doesn't seem to make much sense in your example, you'll have to first extend the file to `pagesize + strlen(buffer) + 1` if you want to write `buf` at that location. More likely you want to start at the beginning of the file, so pass 0 as the last argument to mmap.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me quite a lot of time :)

Comment: BTW just a note as I ended up here on a similar case, but in my case I *was* doing fallocate - however the disk (ram disk) in this case was full - and the memory accesses post successful fallocate and mmap bus errored. Just one to watch out for 8)

Comment: @nos, Thank you for a great solution.

Comment: You sir, are a true legend