# How to fix the Ubuntu 64 bit Linux bus error I get when trying to access the memory mapped address, m_pControl, returned by mmap?

Tags: c++, memory-management, ubuntu-14.04

I would to fix the Ubuntu 64 bit Linux bus error I get when trying to access the memory mapped address, m_pControl, returned by mmap. I tried to memset it but it did not help prevent the bus error on the following source code line after memset. The Windows 7 version of this code apparently does not have a bus error.

```
bool CDataTransferServer::Initialize(int nCameraID, 
                                     CC_SAMPLETYPE nDataType,
                                     unsigned int nImageWidth, 
                                     unsigned int nImageHeight,
                                     unsigned int nMaxFrames)
{
    bool bOkay = true;
    if (m_bInitialized)
        return true;

        char buffer[256];
        m_strMemoryName = L"Global\\SmartCamMem";
                size_t origsize = strlen(m_szObjNameSuffix) + 1;
                const size_t newsize = 100;
                size_t convertedChars = 0;
                wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
                mbstowcs(wcstring, m_szObjNameSuffix,origsize);
                m_strMemoryName += wcstring;    
        wcstombs(buffer,m_strMemoryName.c_str(),256);
        int fd = open(buffer, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
        m_pControl = fd >= 0 ? (CDataTransferControl*)mmap(NULL, m_nFileMapSize,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0) : NULL; 
        if (m_pControl)              
        {   
            memset(m_pControl,0x0,sizeof(m_pControl));
            m_pControl->nConfigurationBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nNewestKeyDataBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nNewestDataBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nBlockHeaders = m_nMaxFrames + m_nConfigBlocks;
            m_pControl->nTimeOfLastClientAccess = ::GetTickCount();
        }
        else
            bOkay = false;
   return bOkay;
```

}

My m_pControl return value is 0x550c6000 and fd is 3.

Here is my test C++ driver program.

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <iostream>
#include  <dlfcn.h>
#include "CameraControlDefs.h"
#include "DataServer.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

   bool (*sayHello)(CDataTransferServer* _this, int nCameraID, CC_SAMPLETYPE nDataType,
                                unsigned int nImageWidth, unsigned int nImageHeight,
                                unsigned int nMaxFrames);


  unsigned int tmp;


  void* handle = dlopen("libDataServer.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!handle)
  {
    std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  // load the symbols
    create_t* create_triangle = (create_t*) dlsym(handle, "create");
    const char* dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        cerr << "Cannot load symbol create: " << dlsym_error << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    destroy_t* destroy_triangle = (destroy_t*) dlsym(handle, "destroy");
    dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        cerr << "Cannot load symbol destroy: " << dlsym_error << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    // create an instance of the class
    CDataTransferServer* poly = create_triangle();


  *(bool **)(&sayHello) = (bool *)dlsym(handle,"_ZN19CDataTransferServer10InitializeEi13CC_SAMPLETYPEjjj");
  if (dlerror())
  {
    std::cerr << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 2;
  }


  printf("ywc = %x\n",poly);


// destroy the class

   (*sayHello)(poly, 5, CC_SAMPLETYPE_MPEG4,128,256,64);
    destroy_triangle(poly);

    // unload the triangle library
  dlclose(handle);



  return 0;

}
```

Please explain the bus error. Please advise on whether I should change any of the arguments to mmap or an alternate approach. Thank you

Comment: I believe this might be the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587935/bus-error-opening-and-mmaping-a-file I will test it in 1 hour. If anyone has a better or similar, please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote and tested this code excerpt early this morning at 4 A.M. I hope this helps other in a similar solution. If you have a question. please enter a comment and I will get back to you.

```
    if (bOkay)
    {

                char buffer[256];
        m_strMemoryName = L"Global\\SmartCamMem";
                size_t origsize = strlen(m_szObjNameSuffix) + 1;
                const size_t newsize = 100;
                size_t convertedChars = 0;
                wchar_t wcstring[newsize];
                mbstowcs(wcstring, m_szObjNameSuffix,origsize);
                m_strMemoryName += wcstring;    
        wcstombs(buffer,m_strMemoryName.c_str(),256);
            unlink(buffer);
        int fd = open(buffer, O_CREAT | O_RDWR);
                printf("fd = %d\n",fd);
                int page_size = getpagesize();
                printf("result = %d\n",posix_fallocate(fd, 0, page_size + m_nFileMapSize + 1));

        m_pControl = fd >= 0 ? (CDataTransferControl*)mmap(NULL, m_nFileMapSize,PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0) : NULL; 
             printf("m_pControl = %x\n",m_pControl);
                if (m_pControl)
        {
            memset(m_pControl, 0,sizeof(m_pControl));
            m_pControl->nConfigurationBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nNewestKeyDataBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nNewestDataBlock = 0xffffffff;
            m_pControl->nBlockHeaders = m_nMaxFrames + m_nConfigBlocks;
            m_pControl->nTimeOfLastClientAccess = ::GetTickCount();
        }
        else
            bOkay = false;

    }
```